# Modify Hex values from executable file in C++ (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, hex, type-conversion

I'm trying to modify an specific section of executable file inserting hex values in my program and writing to it, but I'm having a problem with type-conversion. The only way I found is inserting by `ifs << (BYTE)0x12` but I can not make a dynamic variable to do that.

Here is the function:

```
int FileHexModify(int pos)
{
    fstream ifs;
    ifs.open ("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Modify.exe", fstream::binary | fstream::in | fstream::out);
    std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    ifs.seekp(pos);
    ifs << (BYTE)0x12;
    if (ifs.is_open())
        ifs.close();
    return 0;
}
```

When i try something like

```
char *code = "1b";
ifs.write(code, 16);
```

i get a `31 62` corresponding to `1 b` in hex, but i need an only value `0x1b`. I can not find the way to do it. Can you please show me the way? :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, you need to convert from `"1b"` ? You have a reason to not use `0x1b` directly ?

Comment: By any chance, is `BYTE code = 0x1b; ifs << code;` what you need ? The `<<` operator have different behavior depending on the parameter, so if you want to print a byte, you need to provide a byte (or at least cast).

Answer (score 0):

You'd want `char const* code = "\x1b"`. The `\x` tells the compiler that a hex number follows. Also, `ifs.write(code, 16)` is very wrong. That writes 16 bytes, not one. There aren't even 16 bytes in `code` !